# How to insert multidimentional array to mysql in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a mysql table with field id,meta_key,meta_value. i want to add multiple metavalue and metakeys when i add any listing, here is my controller code

```
        $listingid=145;
        $metakey=array();
        $metavalue=array();

        if($data['submitlisting'])
        {
        if($vehicle_make != "")
        {
            $metakey[]="vehicle_make";
            $metavalue[]=$vehicle_make;
        }   
        if($vehicle_mileage != "")
        {
            $metakey[]="vehicle_mileage";
            $metavalue[]=$vehicle_mileage;
        }
        if($vehicle_year != "")
        {
            $metakey[]="vehicle_year";
            $metavalue[]=$vehicle_year;
        }

        $data['listingmeta']=$this->Classifieds_model->addmeta($listingid,$metakey,$metavalue,$data);
```

here is the model code

```
function addmeta($listingid,$metakey,$metavalue,$data2)
{
    $this->load->database();
    $data = array(
       'classifieds_id' => $listingid ,
       'meta_key' => 'location' ,
       'meta_value' => 'mangalore'
    );

    foreach($data2['listingmeta'] as $meta)
    $this->db->insert('classifieds_meta',
      array(
       'classifieds_id' => $listingid ,
       'meta_key' => 'location' ,
       'meta_value' => 'mangalore'
        )
      );
}
```

but the above code doesnt work, please can someone help?

Comment: You might want to explain on what is it supposed to do, and what is not actually happening there.

Comment: Can you give us the value of $data['submitlisting'] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The propest way, it's better to avoid SQL commands in loops :

```
$insert_batch = array();

for($i=0; $i<count($); $i++)
{
     $insert['classifieds_id'] = $listingid;
     $insert['meta_key'] = $metakey[$i];
     $insert['meta_value'] = $metavalue[$i];

     $insert_batch []= $insert;
}

$this->db->insert_batch('classifieds_meta', $insert_batch);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) Create a simple `model function` just to insert data array. 
(always try to frame your model functions such that they can be re-used)**

```
function addmeta($data)
(
    $this->db->insert('classifieds_meta', $data);
)
```

**2) Now send the `required array` to the model through the `Controller` below**

array(
       'classifieds_id' => $listingid ,
       'meta_key' => 'location' ,
       'meta_value' => 'mangalore'
        )

```
$listingid=145;
$metakey=array();
$metavalue=array();

if($data['submitlisting'])
{
    if($vehicle_make != "")
    {
        $metakey[]="vehicle_make";
        $metavalue[]=$vehicle_make;
    }   
    if($vehicle_mileage != "")
    {
        $metakey[]="vehicle_mileage";
        $metavalue[]=$vehicle_mileage;
    }
    if($vehicle_year != "")
    {
        $metakey[]="vehicle_year";
        $metavalue[]=$vehicle_year;
    }

    $insert = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($metakey); $i++)
    {
         $insert['classifieds_id'] = $listingid;
         $insert['meta_key'] = $metakey[$i];
         $insert['meta_value'] = $metavalue[$i];

         $this->Classifieds_model->addmeta($insert);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can try this code into controller:

```
    $ex=count($this->input->post('ex'));
    $count =count($this->input->post('ex'));
    $data2 =array();
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++)  
    {
                $data2[] = array(
                         'ex' => $ex[$i],
                        );      
       }
   $this->db->insert_batch('table', $data2);
```